# How do i perform arithmetic operations with function pointers?

Tags: c, math, function-pointers, arithmetic-expressions

So..I understand that if i take(`*ptr`) as some function f then

```
res = (*ptr)(a,b) is the same as res = f(a,b).
```

So now my problem is that I have to read in 3 integers. First 2 are the operands, third is the operator e.g. `1 = add, 2 = subtract, 3 = multiply, 4 = divide`. How do I do it without if or switch statements.

I was thinking of two possible solutions

> 1. create 4 pointers and deference each pointer to an arithmetic operation, but with that I still have to do some sort of input
>      validation which would require if or switch statements
> 2. This isn't really a solution but the basic idea would probably by like. if c = operator then I can somehow do something like res =
>      (*ptrc)(a,b) but I don't think there's such a syntax for C

Sample input

```
1 2 1

1 2 2

1 2 3

1 2 4
```

Sample Output

```
 3

-1

 2

 0
```

My Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Datatype Declarations
typedef int (*arithFuncPtr)(int, int);


//Function Prototypes
int add(int x, int y);


int main()
{
    int a, b, optype, res;

    arithFuncPtr ptr;

    //ptr points to the function add
    ptr = add;

    scanf("%i %i", &a, &b);

    res = (*ptr)(a, b);

    printf("%i\n", res);

    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

Comment: to check it i'll have to use an if statement. i'm trying to find a way to check which operator it is without an if statement.

Comment: How about you create an array of function pointers and invoke the appropriate function indexed with a little creativity based on the operation you're performing? (`op-1`, where `op` is your desired operation and your function pointer array includes add, subtract multiply, and divide function addresses respectively.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put you functions pointers in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Datatype Declarations
typedef int (*arithFuncPtr)(int, int);


//Function Prototypes
int add(int x, int y);
int sub(int x, int y);
int mul(int x, int y);
int div(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int a, b, optype, res;

    arithFuncPtr ptr[4];

    //ptr points to the function
    ptr[0] = add;
    ptr[1] = sub;
    ptr[2] = mul;
    ptr[3] = div;

    scanf("%i %i %i", &a, &b, &optype);

    res = (ptr[optype - 1])(a, b);

    printf("%i\n", res);

    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}  

int sub(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;
}  

int mul(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}  

int div(int x, int y)
{
    return x/y;
}
```

Comment: then may i ask what is the point of the typedef int(*arithFuncPtr)(int, int); line? obviously this is a homework assignment :P thanks for the help :)

Comment: okay nevermind I saw its usage in the code. thanks a bunch! I actually already wrote this code without the arithFuncPtr ptr[4]. mustve been confused with typedef. not so clear about it.

Comment: Awesome I wrote the exact same thing. To prevent the out of bounds, and without `if`s, you can use the modulo operation. Here's [my version](https://gist.github.com/CanTheAlmighty/e411590d2a48d2ec9fb1), not worth making another reply for it.